# User input to create factorial

Tags: ruby, factorial, fact

Need some help on making the `def fact(n)` command to work off user input.  My script works great when I input something like "Ruby factorial.rb 5".  However, I need this to run with prompts.  The script should run something like:

```
puts 'Please input a non-negative integer:'
n = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "The factorial of #{n} is #{factorial}
```

Here's what my code looks like now.  Like I said however, it does work.  It's when I add `n = gets.chomp.to_i` before the `def fact(n)` command that I automatically receive a value of 1.  It doesn't matter what number the user puts in, it always returns 1.

```
#!/user/bin/ruby
def fact(n)
  if n==0
    1
  else
    n * fact(n-1)
  end
end
puts fact(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

How do I make this work with the user input?  I think I'm just having a syntax issue, but don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Try `puts 'Please input a non-negative integer'`, then `n = gets.to_i`, then `puts "The factorial of #{n} is #{fact(n)}"`

Comment: you're awesome.  thank you

Comment: Check out the full answer I just gave below. It shows you how to do both of the things you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually seem to be asking for two different things. The first thing you want is an application that does something like this

```
$ ruby factorial.rb
> Please input a non-negative integer
(GET USER INPUT)
> The factorial of (USER INPUT) is (FACTORAIL OF USER INPUT)
```

And a command line tool that does something like this

```
$ fact 10
> 3628800
```

The first one could look something like this

```
def fact(n)
  (1..n).inject(:*)
end
puts 'Please input a non-negative integer'
a = gets.to_i
puts "The factorial of #{a} is #{fact(a)}"
```

The second one could look something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts (1..ARGV[0].to_i).inject(:*)
```